# Python Pandas .groupby().mean() with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use .groupby().mean() on this DataFrame, however, it doesn't omit the NaN values.

Here is the picture of my DataFrame

[image: City_Zhvi_AllHomes]

'Quarters' is my last row so I do transpose to make it the last column, and groupby 'Quarters', then do .mean() for all the counties. I expect to store the new DataFrame in a new variable, with column indexes as county names, and row indexes as 'Quarters', each cell is the mean of 3 cells that share the same County and same 'Quarters' in the previous DataFrame.

So I do:

```
ANSWER = City_Zhvi_AllHomes.T.groupby('Quarters').mean().T
```

But I got:

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

It will work if I do .fillna(0) before .groupby(), here is the picture for that (except I transpose the row and column again)

[image: answer]

But I can't do that since it will affect the result for the mean. So what should I do to tell .mean() to ignore NaN?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't includes images. Provide a [mcve]. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I think need `ANSWER  = groupby('Quarters').mean()`

Comment: I finally got it. Just in case someone might need it. I use **df.astype('float64')** to change the type from 'object' to 'float64', then the .mean() works, without saying "No numeric types to aggregate".